# Retrieve duplicate results when searching for duplicate keys?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am in a situation that feels a little odd ... I have a list of keys *deliberately* containing duplicates. For the sake of the arguments lets assume this list looks like `[1,2,3,2,1]`. Currently the code to fetch the documents belonging to these Ids loops over the list of keys, calls `findOne()` and pushes the document into an array.

So we have a construct like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  documents.push(db.items.findOne(keys[i]);
}
```

I am wondering whether there is a way to do this in a more ... elegant ... fashion, preferably with a single query? Keeping the order would be a plus but is not strictly required.

**Edit:**
Please note that this is a MongoDB question. I am looking for a way to substitute the above loop with a single call to db.items.find().

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: That doesn't look related to me ..?

Comment: is there only one document for each key?

Comment: Yes, the keys point to unique documents.

Comment: So you basically just want to find documents which match any element an array.
Is this what are looking for?:
` db.items.find({key: {"$in: [arrayvalue1, arrayvalue2]"}});

Comment: No, using the `$in` Operator would not retrieve the documents multiple times if I specify the key multiple times.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't think we are understanding your question.

This is what you get with `$in`, but I'm guessing you don't want:
[pastebin.com/6JHMeZLG](http://pastebin.com/6JHMeZLG)

Comment: I would want that `db.test.find({key: {"$in":[1,3,3]}})` retrieves the document with the ID 3 twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct way to retrieve a list for duplicate keys, but since you said that keys are unique you could do it using `$in` and some looping:

```
var keys = [1,2,3,2,1];
var docHash = {}; //auxiliary hashtable containing mapping id -> document

var documents = []; //the result

db.items.find({id : {$in : keys}})
     .forEach(
         function(doc) {
             //if multiple documents can have the same key change it to:
             // if (docHash[doc.id]) { 
             //     docHash[doc.id].push(doc);
             // } else {
             //     docHash[doc.id] = [doc];
             // } 
             docHash[doc.id] = doc; 
         });

keys.forEach(function(i) {
     // if multiple documents can have the same key change it to:
     // docHash[i].forEach(function(item) {documents.push(item);});
     documents.push(docHash[i]);
}
```

Note that, while it's longer than the original, it queries the database only once. As a bonus it returns documents in the same order as the given keys.

Comment: Yes, thats a great substitute!

Answer (score 0):

use for-each function in java-script  that should help you a bit:

```
for (var i in keys) {// i will be  1 ,2 ,3 ,3 ,1
   documents.push(db.items.findOne(i);      
 }
```

or i might've missed your questions intention complety?
but then again duplicate keys do not exist in any array..

```
var used=Array();
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  if (!used[keys[i]]){
       used[keys[i]]=1;
       documents.push(db.items.findOne(keys[i]);}
}
```

that will ignore any duplicates and count them as one eather that or you can run query on the keys rendering them in to a new array that does not contains duplicates

Comment: Maybe I should add some emphasis that this is a MongoDB question ... I am looking for a way to optimise the multiple calls of findOne() by using a single find() operation.

Comment: Ok i'm not a big expert but let me get this you have an array of data that gets one of those right?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean ... The duplicate keys are there on purpose, I don't want to filter them.

Comment: Sounds like your schema choice isn't well suited for the use case you have.